# Space in regex character class producing weird results

Tags: regex

So I was working on some regex and came across some weird behavior in regex.

I had a character class in the regex that included a bunch of characters (alphanumeric) and ended with a space, a dash, and a plus. The weird behavior is reproducable using the following regex.

```
^[ -+]*$
```

So what happens is that a space is valid text input and so is the plus. However, for some reason the dash is not valid text input. The regex can be fixed by rearranging the charaters in the class as so:

```
^[ +-]*$
```

Now all the characters are valid input. This has been reproduced in Chrome using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2uD/) and also using Expresso.

My question is basically, am I doing something wrong or is this just weird? :)

Comment: Don't you have to escape the +?

Comment: @KevinL No, within a character class `+` represents a literal `+` character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-` character has special meaning inside character classes. When it appears between two characters, it creates a range, e.g. `[0-9]` matches any character between `0` and `9`, inclusive. However, when placed at the start or the end of the character class (or when escaped) it represents a literal `-` character.

- `[ -+]` will match any character between a space (char code 32) and a `+` (char code 43), inclusive.
- `[ +-]` will match a space (char code 32), a `+` (char code 43), or a `-` (char code 45)

Comment: Of course.. I don't know why I didn't think of that... However, escaping the dash works in expresso, but not in js.

Comment: Ok... so escaping the dash works in js if you use the /regex/gim declaration syntax, but not if you do new RegExp(regexString).

Comment: @GísliKonráð Remember that you need to escape the \ inside string literals. Try `new RegExp("[ \\-+]")`

Comment: yeah... I ended up doing that... I don't know why I brainfarted all over the place with this one, but I did find it interesting. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because in first you were treating `-` as "to" or range operator as in `a-z`

So it is becoming `space to +` which is a range. Either escape `-` by prepending a `\` or put it at first or at last.